# Set the default code language for tags to "default" instead of "none"

Tags: support, status-completed, highlighting-code

I noticed that there are many tags for which the code language used for code highlighting is set to "none," which means that a question using one or more of those tags would not use any highlighting syntax. It would be better to have it set to "default," which normally works fine for languages using a C-like syntax (such as in the case of PHP and JavaScript), for XML, and HTML.

As normally the code snippets are in PHP, JavaScript, or HTML, the "default" option should work for most the cases, and it should be preferable to "none."

Comment: +1 I agree, would make a lot of sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems reasonable. I adjusted the [xml](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml) and [html](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) tags to use default syntax highlighting instead of none.

Feel free to adjust other tags as needed from the tags' info pages.

Comment: I thought there were a way to set it as default value that would be used for all the tags for which a value has not been set. It's not a matter of setting it for X tags, but to set it as default value as it happens with Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't think it makes sense to set it as default for all tags. The "default" setting means Prettify will try to infer the language in a code block and that can result in bizarre highlighting when there is no code at all, since not every tag refers to a programming language but even code-less questions sometimes feature code blocks for representing fixed-format text.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't think the default for new tags on SO is "default" either. Not every tag on SO has syntax highlighting associated with it.

Comment: I could have misunderstood what I was said. What is the workflow, in this case? Do I check if X questions out of Y use code, and then change the language setting? Is it enough, if two questions use code?